# How to set a column value if unavailable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which is as follows .
TABLE NAME : TESTNUMBERS

```
ID(INT)   NUMBER(INT)    NAME(NVARCHAR(50))
1         1             Test
2         1             Test
3         2             Test2
```

when i insert the NUMBER column i need to increment if unavailable and if available then the max id value + 1 and also ensure if the number has been passed as an argument then save it as is.(This is to ensure a constraint that rows with NAME as same  will have  NUMBER column same too).

I have written an SP but there a few syntax issues.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_STOREDPROC
@Name           NVARCHAR(50),
@Number         INT = 0,
@ID INT      
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @IncrementID SMALLINT; SET @IncrementID=1;   
        DECLARE @IncrementNumber INT; SET @IncrementNumber = 1;
        BEGIN TRAN
        BEGIN
        IF @Number = 0
        BEGIN            
         SET @Number =
         SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(Number),0)+@IncrementNumber
         from TESTNUMBERS
        END

            INSERT INTO TESTNUMBERS
                       ([ID]
                       ,[Name]
                       ,[Number])

            SELECT  ISNULL(MAX([ID]),0)+@IncrementID as [ID]                                            
                                               ,@Name
                                               ,@Number                                 
            FROM   TESTNUMBERS  
            --return the ID of the column inserted
            SELECT MAX([ID]) from TESTNUMBERS  
        END
        COMMIT TRAN
 END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--TO DO      
END CATCH
END    
GO
```

How do i improve and correct this SP?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: If the ID is autogenerated, why are you inserting a value for it? What happens if the insert fail? You're left with an open transaction

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @JLo Please note the updated question

Comment: @Thomas version is 10.0 SQLServer2008

Comment: a common alternative to sp_ is usp_. Do you have control of the table design? Name does not describe ID, it describes number, so this should be in a separate table that describes what number is, with a foreign key pointing back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST
        @Name           NVARCHAR(50),
        @Number         INT = 0,
        @ID INT      
        AS
        BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON
        BEGIN TRY
                DECLARE @IncrementID SMALLINT; SET @IncrementID=1;   
                DECLARE @IncrementNumber INT; SET @IncrementNumber = 1;
                BEGIN TRAN
                BEGIN
                IF @Number = 0
                *BEGIN            
                 **SET @Number =(SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(Number),0)+@IncrementNumber from TESTNUMBERS)***
                END

                    INSERT INTO TESTNUMBERS
                               ([ID]
                               ,[Name]
                               ,[Number])

                    SELECT  ISNULL(MAX([ID]),0)+@IncrementID as [ID]                                            
                                                       ,@Name
                                                       ,@Number                                 
                    FROM   TESTNUMBERS  
                    --return the ID of the column inserted
                    SELECT MAX([ID]) from TESTNUMBERS  
                END
                COMMIT TRAN
         END try
         **BEGIN CATCH
          ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH**  
         end
```

there are two syntax error was in you stored procedure

1. you should have to add round bracket when you assign value to any variable through sql select query.
2. i think u forgot about catch block after try block which is necessary else who will catch your exception and do the necessary transaction after error :), additionally your procedure have good logic, keep it up. for syntax google is there....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usd_TEST_STOREDPROC

      @Name NVARCHAR(50)
    , @Number INT = 0
    , @ID INT   

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE 
              @IncrementID SMALLINT = 1 
            , @IncrementNumber INT = 1 

        BEGIN TRAN BEGIN

            SELECT @Number = ISNULL(MAX(Number), 0) + @IncrementNumber
            FROM dbo.TESTNUMBERS
            WHERE @Number = 0

            INSERT INTO dbo.TESTNUMBERS([ID], [Name], [Number])
            SELECT 
                  ISNULL(MAX([ID]), 0) + @IncrementID                                            
                , @Name
                , @Number                                 
            FROM dbo.TESTNUMBERS

            SELECT MAX([ID]) 
            FROM dbo.TESTNUMBERS

        END

        COMMIT TRAN

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

END
```